# Reading floats in C++ equivalent in Java

Tags: java, floating-point, binary

I have a binary file which supposed to contain 32-bit floating point numbers.
This file was written out from Objective-C code.
My task is to read this file in Java.

I think i managed to do it in C++:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float f;
    std::ifstream fin("effect_0.cube", std::ios::binary);
    while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f), sizeof(float))) {
      std::cout << f << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is how i interpret a float in Java

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("effect_0.cube");
DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(is);
float f = dataInputStream.readFloat();
```

But this returns totally wrong values.

I am running all this on OSX.

The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GQwe8WZGZdhEYDLE90e6V6KtlKQi75fC/view?usp=sharing). It is very small. The values from C++ seem right, because they are in the correct range, but i got totally different values in Java. I also provide the `hexdump -n 16 -s 256`:

```
0000100 00 00 00 00 91 90 90 3e 00 00 00 00 00 00 80 3f
0000110
```

Comment: Could you add a hex dump of a few of your floats from the file? Preferably ones whose value you know.

Comment: I  uploaded the file, it is a few kilobytes.

Comment: I do not follow links from StackOverflow questions. I do agree with the endianness suggestion.

Comment: I added the hexdump to so the question is more complete now for future reference.

Comment: 0x3f800000 is 1.0 in 32-bit float, so it is definitely a little-endian file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C code is writing in CPU [endian order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), which for Intel processors is **little-endian**.

`DataInputStream` is reading in network byte order, which is **big-endian**.

The best way to read `float` value in Java, where you can control the endian order, is to use a [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html).

Sample code:

```
try (InputStream is = new FileInputStream("effect_0.cube")) {
    ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
    for (int len; (len = is.read(buf.array())) == 4; ) {
        buf.rewind();
        float f = buf.getFloat();
        System.out.println(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no newline in the file, so it's 4-byte chunks.

Comment: @RalfKleberhoff Sorry, I read code in question as the C code *writing* the data to the file.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have the code which wrote the file. The C++ code in the question correctly reads it (I think). But I hope your answer points out the problem (endianness). I will try it tomorrow and report back. Thanks!